# Authenticate users inside and outside the Teams environment when using the Teams Toolkit?

Tags: authentication, msal

I'm developing a Team App (personal tab) using the Teams Toolkit (React, Typescript, Fluent components). There're no problems when running inside Teams, however when pressing the globe icon (top right) and opening app in the browser I'm unable to authenticate the user because the teams SDK doesn't initialize correctly (because it running outside the Teams environment and the authentication providers rely on the SDK to initialize)

I haven't found a sample for this escenario, all seems to asume the Team App runs inside Teams, but all Tabs have an icon to run it outside in the browser and the documentation is not very clear about how to handle this. I read somewhere about doing a fallback to msal, but not sample on how to do it.

Have anyone solved this issue? any advise or sample would be appreciated

Thanks

Tried the different provider in the Teams Toolkit with no success